# Connecting your application with database

Tags: java, mysql, database, authentication

I'm pretty beginner with AndroidStudio and java, I know the basics and some additional stuff and how generally java works but.
...creating applications from nothing in java is hard ._.
What I would like to do is :
-I have created a database on my personal computer with the data I need (id, logins and passwords)
I would like to make a very simple app in **AndroidStudio**, that's important, that would check login and password and display success on login and fail if fail.
I have already created a php script and put it into a simple html website, everything works perfectly but when it comes to an application....oof.
tl;dr
I would need help how to make a simple login system in AndroidStudio and would use the app to log in to my database on my pc (both connected to same network)
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Get started here https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an easy begginer approach will be to first add apache dependency in your app:module file then make http requests. Check this sample. https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/04/android-login-registration-php-mysql-client.html